# Expectation E(XY) of two dependent variables

Tags: probability

If X and Y are 2 dependent variables, how does their combined expectation look? For example, if flipping a fair coin n times, with X representing the number of heads and Y representing the number of tails. How would I calculate E[XY], and what's the intuition behind it?

Comment: What you need is the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$. Then e.g. in discrete case $\mathbb EXY=\sum_{x,y}xyP(X=x,Y=y)$. If there is a PDF then $\mathbb EXY=\int xyf_X(x,y)dxdy$ (both under condition that the expectation exists, of course). In your example we are dealing with the ultimate counterpart of being independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example of coin tosses, you actually have $Y=n-X$. So $E[XY]=E[X(n-X)]= nE[X] - E\left[X^2\right]$.

Since $X\sim \mathrm{Binomial}(n,p)$, where $p$ is the probability of heads on a single coin toss, you can calculate this by using the formula for $E[X]$ and $E\left[X^2\right]$ when $X$ has such distribution. (You can find the formula for $E\left[X^2\right]$ at [Calculating the Second Moment of a Binomial Random Variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2477817/calculating-the-second-moment-of-a-binomial-random-variable).)

Comment: What if X and Y are correlated but not mirrors of each other? For example throwing a die, where X is the case that 3 is received and Y is the case that 4 is received

Comment: You mean $X$ is the number of $3$'s rolled in $n$ rolls and $Y$ similarly for $4$?

Comment: X represents the number of 3's, Y the number of 4's yes

Comment: $\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$In that case, we have $E[XY] = \left(n^2-n\right)\cdot \frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$. This is a special case of the general fact that if $(X_1,\ldots, X_k)$ has a *multinomial distribution* with $n$ trials and success probabilities $p_1,\ldots , p_k$, then $E\left[X_i X_j\right] = \left(n^2-n\right)p_i p_j$. See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669513/find-the-covariances-of-a-multinomial-distribution) for a proof of this, and search up "multinomial distribution" online for more information about this distribution.

Comment: (Note in that link, their $r$ is my $n$ above, and their $n$ is my $k$ above. Also $k=6$ for standard dice rolls.)

Comment: Also that formula is for $i\ne j$.